# React Checkbox Component Unchecking Issue - All Checkboxes Cleared and Array Refilled on Slide Change

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, carbon-components

I'm encountering a perplexing issue in a React application where I have implemented a set of checkboxes. The initial state is such that all checkboxes are selected by default. However, when I uncheck any checkbox, it seems to clear all the checkboxes and retain only the unchecked one. Additionally, upon moving to the next slide and returning, the array holding the selected checkbox values is refilled with all the default values.

```
import React from "react";
import { Checkbox } from "@carbon/react";

const CheckBoxInput = ({
  item,
  data,
  setSelectedCheckboxValues,
  selectedCheckboxValues,
}) => {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = React.useState(true);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setIsChecked(selectedCheckboxValues.includes(item.title));
  }, [selectedCheckboxValues, item.title]);

  const handleCheckBoxChange = React.useCallback(
    (event, { checked, id }) => {
      const updatedValues = selectedCheckboxValues.includes(id)
        ? selectedCheckboxValues.filter((val) => val !== id)
        : [...selectedCheckboxValues, id];
      setSelectedCheckboxValues(updatedValues);
    },
    [selectedCheckboxValues, setSelectedCheckboxValues]
  );

  return (
    <>
      <Checkbox
        onChange={handleCheckBoxChange}
        labelText={item.title}
        id={item.title}
        defaultChecked={isChecked}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default CheckBoxInput;
```

Issue:

1. Unchecking a checkbox results in clearing all checkboxes, keeping only the one that is unchecked.
2. Moving to the next slide and returning refills the selectedCheckboxValues array with all default values.

[Sandbox link with the problem](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/slider-jlltyw?file=%2Fcomponents%2FCheckboxes.js)

Expected Behavior:

1. Unchecking a checkbox should update the array, keeping the other checkboxes in their current state.
2. Moving between slides should not affect the state of the checkboxes or the selectedCheckboxValues array.

Any assistance or guidance on resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

**Update**

Adding the items to the array on component mount (`useEffect with empty dependency array`) did the thing.

Slides.js

```
React.useEffect(() => {
    if (slides[currentSlide]?.content) {
      const allCheckboxValues = slides[currentSlide].content.map(
        (item) => item.title
      );
      setSelectedCheckboxValues(allCheckboxValues);
    }
  }, []);
```

But then I figured out that when I swap the position of content array from first element to any other position, it will stop working again.

Same code in another sandbox with the difference that content array is not in the first object of the slides array:
[Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/slider-forked-f3rkl9?file=%2Findex.js%3A29%2C7)

New Array

```
const SLIDES = [
  {
    title: "Checkboxes",
    text: "We're gonna do 3 fundamental exercises.",
  },
  {
    title: "First, 10 push-ups",
    text: "Do 10 reps. Remember about full range of motion. Don't rush.",
    content: [
      {
        title: "Test1",
      },
      {
        title: "Test2",
      },
      {
        title: "Test3",
      },
      {
        title: "Test4",
      },
      {
        title: "Test5",
      },
    ],
...rest of the elements
  },
];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The issue may be related to the timing of when the effect runs and when the content is available.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way so solve the Problem was to add the array of checkbox values on the initialization of the state which is responsible for holding the checked checkbox values and it works fine. 
[Sandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/slider-jlltyw?file=%2Fcomponents%2FCheckboxes.js%3A18%2C5)

```
  const content = ["Test1", "Test2", "Test3", "Test4", "Test5"];
  const [selectedCheckboxValues, setSelectedCheckboxValues] =
    React.useState(content);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that the isChecked state is not being updated correctly when a checkbox is unchecked, and this is causing undesired behavior.

To fix this issue, you can directly use the isChecked state to determine the checked state of the checkbox instead of relying on defaultChecked

```js
import React from "react";
import { Checkbox } from "@carbon/react";

const CheckBoxInput = ({
  item,
  selectedCheckboxValues,
  setSelectedCheckboxValues,
}) => {
  const isChecked = selectedCheckboxValues.includes(item.title);

  const handleCheckBoxChange = (event, { id }) => {
    const updatedValues = selectedCheckboxValues.includes(id)
      ? selectedCheckboxValues.filter((val) => val !== id)
      : [...selectedCheckboxValues, id];
    setSelectedCheckboxValues(updatedValues);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Checkbox
        onChange={handleCheckBoxChange}
        labelText={item.title}
        id={item.title}
        checked={isChecked}
      />
    </>
  );
};

export default CheckBoxInput;
```

Comment: Hi @Nacho,
thanks for the answer. Looks good already. 
But the problem is that all the checkboxes should be already selected/checked by default.